# Rental car recommendations for Bali

Tags: car-rentals, bali

My wife and I are considering to go to Bali for a little bit more than two weeks next year October. 
We were looking at rental car companies and were wondering which ones are trustworthy and which one we should stay away from. We're familiar with Avis, but they only have expensive cars available in our time that we are there.
That's why we're looking for price and trust worthy alternatives. We don't need big SUV's, a normal compact car would suit us fine.
Also a rental car company that offers sufficient insurances for a reasonable price.
Preferably we'd have a rental car company that doesn't use very old models where the rust rains down when you hit the car.

So what are the car rental companies we should avoid, and which ones can we trust? And maybe other Bali specific tips concerning rental cars would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: I suggest renting a car with a driver, which addresses many of your concerns as well as some others (parking, erratic driving style, etc).

Comment: This is a shopping question, and I vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with your specific situation, I would advise you to **reconsider driving yourself on Bali**.  The roads are not up to Western standards, particularly up in the mountains, and driving can be erratic and actively dangerous, particularly if you're not used it.

Instead, I would suggest **using Uber or Grab**, which are very reasonably priced by Western standards (Rp 50,000/US$3 for most hops around Seminyak/Kuta), or get **a car with driver** for a full day (from Rp 500,000/US$30).

Comment: Are the road conditions really that bad? Or is it more the fellow road user mentality that make it hard to drive there?

Comment: Both.  Bali is a very hilly place and most roads are narrow, twisty, and full of potholes, chickens, etc.  Add in reckless driving and something as basic as going from Kuta to Ubud can be pretty scary.  I certainly wouldn't advise renting a car if you haven't experienced what you're in for first.